# Python 3 binary search a sorted variable (list of numbers)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, binary-search

Hello there :) I was writing a program that uses binary search through a sorted list. it should work as follows: python find.py 3 1 2 3

the program should look for 3 in the numbers 1 2 and 3

it should return true and print found needle if it is in 1 2 and 3,
if it is not in 1 2 and 3 if should return false and print did not find....

```
def binary_search(needle, haystack):
    first = 0
    last = len(haystack) - 1
    itemlist = str(input(haystack))
    sorted(itemlist)

    while first <= last:
        mid = (first + last) / 2
        if itemlist[mid] == needle :
            print("Found the needle in the haystack")
            return True
        elif needle < itemlist[mid]:
            last = mid - 1
        else:
            first = mid + 1 
        if not True:
            print("Did not find the needle in the haystack")
            return False
```

so I tried implementing a standard binary search algorithm, but every version I come across does not take the first number as the item you need to search for in all the following numbers to come...
So my question is, how do I set the first variable as the "item" and then everything to come as a list that may or may not contain the item?

I also need to sort that list of x length, so i Tried the sorted function, but since the list can be of any length, i need to sort a variable? I got kinda stuck there.... Any tips on these topics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) is a list containing the command line arguments used to invoke the python process. `sys.argv[0]` is the name of the script and `sys.arv[1:]` are the remaining arguments. Access it like this:

```
def binary_search(needle, haystack):
    print('binary_search(): needle = {}, haystack = {}'.format(needle, haystack))
    # your implementation here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    if len(sys.argv) > 2:
        needle = sys.argv[1]
        haystack = sys.argv[2:]
        binary_search(needle, haystack)
    else:
        print('Usage: {} needle haystack...'.format(sys.argv[0]))
```

---

If you need to sort the haystack first, use [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted):

```
binary_search(needle, sorted(haystack))
```

However, there is little point in sorting first because that has *O(n log n)* time complexity, whereas a linear search has only *O(n)* time complexity. Therefore, if the input is unsorted, it's better to just search by iterating over the list until the target is found.

---

Finally, you might need to convert the input to numeric values in order for the search to work. You can use `int()` for that:

```
        needle = int(sys.argv[1])
        haystack = [int(s) for s in sys.argv[2:]]
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks for replying! You helped me out a lot here, however, when I run it now it says: typeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float

Comment: And the Error has to do with the lines: binary_search(int(needle), sorted(int(s) for s in haystack)) and the line: if haystack[mid] == needle:

Comment: @mhawke timsort (the default sort algorithm in Python) has O(n log n) complexity _in the worst case_ only - on already sorted data it's linear.

Comment: I think there is still something wrong with: if haystack[mid] == needle: ................. it says that list indices must be integers or slices, not float, and I define mid as something defined by 2, so maybe it gives the error because mid can be 0.5? I tried using int(mid) but that doesnt work because mid is already an int...

Comment: @RubenWeijers I assume you're using Python 3 - if so you want `mid = round((first + last) / 2)`

Comment: @RubenWeijers `int(someint)` does work as expected by returning `someint` ;)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: according to https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity the _average case_ and worst case for sorting a list is _O(n log n)_. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) agrees. It's misleading to state that _O(n log n)_ is only for the worst case - even if it's linear on already sorted data. If OP knows that the data is sorted there is no issue, just use binary search. Otherwise one should assume the average case and you might as well use a linear search.

Answer (score 0):

Binary search is part of the standard library. Here is how to use it for your problem:

```
import sys
import bisect

argv = [int(_) for _ in sys.argv[1:]]
x = argv.pop(0)
i = bisect.bisect_left(argv, x)
print("Found:", i != len(argv) and argv[i] == x)
```

Also, the problem only makes sense if the input list is already sorted. If it's not, simply use `x in argv`, which is linear (sorting the list is linearithmic).